# Multiple AppDomain leaking some objects

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, appdomain

I'm trying to create a plugin system. For now, I have a system which can load and unload some dynamic libraries on runtime.

I create a AppDomain this way:
`AppDomain` is a `private` member variable.
`RemoteLoader` is a private member variable.

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
    ApplicationName = assemblyName,
    ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile,
};

AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName, null, setup);
remoteLoader = (RemoteLoader)AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName, typeName);
```

`RemoteLoader` keep the list of available `Assemblies`, can create objects and find objects.
The `AppDomain` is correctly created. And when I unload, I can see the `AppDomain` disappearing from module list on Visual Studio.

I'm running Jetbrains dotMemory to find memory leak.

My test for now is:

- Load the service, without any plugin
- Snapshot
- Load some plugin
- Let the plugin work for a while
- Unload the plugin (unloading the entire AppDomain)
- Snapshot

When I compare the two snapshots I can see some objects that never disappear.

Some `strings` with following texts:

- "STEP_Service.Contract.ModuleBase, STEP_Service.Contract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
- "/6ceffbca_d8b4_43be_91ac_39b8cb09ef37/s5bbue3ddey9xxfuevnmvmv9_158.rem"
- "c6360995_32bd_46d9_b83b_3fbac3c58c6a/w1ntjmpe4s+1zp1rkmrio_dy_141.rem"

I can't figure out what is happening. The Key Retention Paths show me that:
[[image: 1]]

The Stack Trace:
[image]

Some `RuntimeMethodInfo` are leaking:
[image]

Other objects like: 
[image]

No exceptions is thrown by unload function or any place.

My `Dispose` method call the `Unload` that is defined like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Unloads the plugins
/// </summary>
public void Unload()
{
    if (AppDomain == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(AppDomain));

    AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain);
    remoteLoader.Dispose();
    AppDomain = null;
    remoteLoader = null;
}
```

I know I didn't provide so much code but I really don't know exactly what code I need to give.
If something is missing please ask for.

Every `class` is derived from `MarshalByRefObject` and just for test I marked a lot of fields as `NonSerializable`.

On my concept when I call `static` method `Unload` of `AppDomain class`, everything inside the AppDomain must be released.

**EDIT**
After a couple minutes executing my service I can see the objects:

[image]

Seems like the CrossAppDomainData and other objects (holded by it self) is growing. The object is placed at Generation 2 of GC.

**EDIT**
After one hour, I can see 2794 NewObjects of type `CrossAppDomainData` and a couple other objects holded by it

- CrossAppDomainData
- CrossAppDomainSink
- Int64

[image]

**EDIT**
After couple hours, I can see around 32k objects of CrossAppDomainSink, CrossAppDomainData and Int64. The memory of my service grown up from 8k to 17k

**EDIT**
I discovered the problem but I don't know why this is happening.
To discover the issue, I recreated my service step by step.
Everthing works fine when I load/unload appdomains a lot of times. Everything is released properly and the memory is ok. 
But in the next step which is load that dll on another application to have the power of unload, update and load again, something is leaking.

On other words, my actual scenario is:

- Service which loads a **Core DLL** on another AppDomain
- The **Core DLL** can load plugins on runtime
- The **Core DLL** can be changed on runtime

  - FileSystemWatcher can monitor the folder for changes on CoreDLL. When this happen, the service unloads the CoreDLL after all work is done, loads the new one and start the work again.

The loaded dll (**CoreDLL**) do the hard work of loading the plugins, watch the plugin folder, and other things. The service only exists to carrie the **CoreDLL** to have the power of update himself.

So... why the objects mentioned before are leaking? The calls are made by the **CoreDLL** and not by the service.

Comment: `mscorlib` is always loaded domain-neutral, that means, all app domains share the same `mscorlib`. Your app domain indeed uses the `mscorlib` (because it's just the core assembly for all). Many types of `mscorlib` are serializable, so the objects will be marshalled from your custom app domain to the default app domain. Strings have weak identity - they can be directly accessed across all app domains. Do you have *particular* issues or suspect a memory leak?

Comment: @dymanoid I have a memory leak. Like you can see on screenshots, the dotMemory  show me the `strings` and other objects like `RuntimeMethodInfo`, `ParameterInfo` being created. But when I  run a third or more snapshot and compare, the objects still there. The strings are some assemblies names and other things (on post I put some examples)

Comment: This isn't a memory leak per se. There are always some system objects like `RuntimeMethodInfo` that will be created and kept alive by the runtime, and you can't control that. If you have no leaking user objects, you have no memory leaks.

Comment: @dymanoid I get it. But why my memory continous to incress even the dotMemory doesn't show any object handled by me growing? It's just the strings, weakreferences, crossappdomainsink growing and growing

Comment: Do you have an issue with that? Are you running out of memory? Are these lots of megabytes or just a couple of kilobytes? The GC won't collect the garbage as fast as possible. It uses heuristics and the GC generations to determine when to collect.

Comment: @dymanoid i've a service. People don't like to see services using much memory. I edited my post with another screenshot. After couple minutes, the objects I mentioned before are not released yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200310/discussion-between-kevin-kouketsu-and-dymanoid).